# Extract parts of pretty url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url, anchor

I have a dynamically generated anchor like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/users/activate/43" class="btn btn-danger">Inactive</a>
```

In the above url after the part `http://www.example.com/users/`, I want to extract

```
var status = activate;
var id = 43
```

How can you get this done in jquery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

USe split() for that

```
var urlSplit=$(".btn").attr("href").split("/");
 alert(urlSplit[urlSplit.length-1]);
 alert(urlSplit[urlSplit.length-2]);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/195/)

Answer (score 1):

```
function extract_url(string) {
    var parts = string.replace("http://www.example.com/users/", "").split("/");
    return [parts[0], parts[1]];
}

extract_url("http://www.example.com/users/activate/43");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just `pop` twice:

```
var a = "http://www.example.com/users/activate/43".split("/");
var id = a.pop();
var status = a.pop();
```